# How can solve problem in installing build tools

Tags: python, node.js, windows, powershell, build-tools

I'm trying to install build tools on my OS (Windows 10) but it always stay in the same state. Like picture [Build tools error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPOi2.png)

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install --global windows-build-tools
npm WARN deprecated windows-build-tools@5.2.2: Node.js now includes build tools for Windows. You probably no longer need this tool. See https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

> windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools
> node ./dist/index.js



Downloading python-2.7.15.amd64.msi
[>                                            ] 0.0% (0 B/s)
Downloaded python-2.7.15.amd64.msi. Saved to C:\Users\user\.windows-build-tools\python-2.7.15.amd64.msi.
Downloading vs_BuildTools.exe
[>                                            ] 0.0% (0 B/s)
Downloaded vs_BuildTools.exe. Saved to C:\Users\user\.windows-build-tools\vs_BuildTools.exe.

Starting installation...
Launched installers, now waiting for them to finish.
This will likely take some time - please be patient!

Status from the installers:
---------- Visual Studio Build Tools ----------
Still waiting for installer log file...
------------------- Python --------------------
Successfully installed Python 2.7
```

What is the problem. Can not install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the NPM page at https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools

```
This package has been deprecated
Author message:

Node.js now includes build tools for Windows. You probably no longer need this tool. See https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools for details.
```

You only need to install python by your self if you haven't already for the builds